# htaccess. give a 404 error first, and then redirect .com/? dynamic php pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

i see that Google in error has indexed thousands of urls that are not in the sitemap.xml.

These urls probably are considered as duplicate content (according to Google only).

I would need to deindex them fairly quickly. So would a 410 gone or a 404 not found status would be more handy.

in htaccess i would like to redirect anything with after the domain name .com/?

```
 www.domain.com/?KKId=xxx
 www.domain.com/?bid=xx
 www.domain.com/?page=xxxx
```

**could we also get these url's to redirect as above, with 410 gone status**

```
www.domain.com/page.php?bid=1&page=xxx
www.domain.com/page.php?bid=2&page=xxx
www.domain.com/page.php?bid=3&page=xxx
www.domain.com/page.php?bid=5&page=xxx
www.domain.com/page.php?bid=6&page=xxx
www.domain.com/page.php?bid=7&page=xxx
www.domain.com/page.php?bid=8&page=xxx
www.domain.com/page.php?bid=9&page=xxx
```

to this page

```
www.domain.com/page.php?bid=4&page=xxx
```

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root, ideally above any other rules you may already have there:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule ^$ - [L,R=410]
```

You can replace the `R=410` with a `R=404` if you'd rather have a "Not Found" response.

Comment: the code worked just perfectly.! also seo wise., do you think to give 100's of 404 status is good, or 410 is better so the crawlers don't come back to fetch it (and save some bandwith)